# Selecting points intersecting two different polygon extents QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, intersection, overlapping-features

I have three layers:

1. points
2. polygon1
3. polygon2

Polygon1 and polygon2 are overlapped, but the extent of polygon1 is smallar than polygon2. The points layer is overlapping polygon1 and polygon2. I want to select points that intersect polygon2 and not in polygon1. If I use "select by location", it will include points overlapped polygon1. How can I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I correctly understand your problem, you can use Select Features By Expression on your points layer.

With your point layer selected, open the Select Features By Expression dialog:

[image]

And enter the following expression (substitute 'poly2' and 'poly1') with the names of your polygon layers:

```
overlay_intersects('poly2') AND NOT overlay_intersects('poly1')
```

Then click 'Select Features'

Results:

[image]

---

**Edit**: To speed up the operation, it may help to create spatial indexes on layers. You can do this with the [Create Spatial Index](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#create-spatial-index) algorithm from the processing toolbox.

Alternatively, a pyqgis approach using `QgsSpatialIndex` and `QgsGeometryEngine` should be quite fast. You can try the running following script from the Python console. Just change the layer names in the first 3 lines to match your own.

```py
# Change layer names below to match your layers
point_layer_name = 'points'
poly1_layer_name = 'poly1' # Smaller polygons
poly2_layer_name = 'poly2' # Larger polygons

project = QgsProject.instance()
points = project.mapLayersByName(point_layer_name)[0]
poly1 = project.mapLayersByName(poly1_layer_name)[0]
poly2 = project.mapLayersByName(poly2_layer_name)[0]

sp_idx = QgsSpatialIndex(points.getFeatures())

point_ids = []

for p2 in poly2.getFeatures():
    p2_geom = p2.geometry()
    pnt_ids = sp_idx.intersects(p2_geom.boundingBox())
    poly2_engine = QgsGeometry.createGeometryEngine(p2_geom.constGet())
    poly2_engine.prepareGeometry()
    p1_feats = [p1 for p1 in poly1.getFeatures() if poly2_engine.intersects(p1.geometry().constGet())]
    if not p1_feats:
        for pt in points.getFeatures(pnt_ids):
            if poly2_engine.contains(pt.geometry().constGet()):
                point_ids.append(pt.id())
    else:
        p1_geom = QgsGeometry.collectGeometry([f.geometry() for f in p1_feats])
        poly1_engine = QgsGeometry.createGeometryEngine(p1_geom.constGet())
        poly1_engine.prepareGeometry()
        for pt in points.getFeatures(pnt_ids):
            if poly2_engine.contains(pt.geometry().constGet()) and not poly1_engine.contains(pt.geometry().constGet()):
                point_ids.append(pt.id())
        
points.selectByIds(point_ids)
```

Comment: This is what I wanted! but when I searched for ovarlay_intersects(), It is not under geometry. If I print the function in the expression window, it says the function is not known. I am using QGIS 3.6. Is there a plugin for these functions? Many thanks.

Comment: I found it after updating the QGIS. Thanks @Ben.

Comment: A follow up question. My data is so big, it runs forever. Is there a way to speed up the selection (e.g., python script)?

Comment: @Hamad, see edits to my answer.

Comment: I got an execution error @Ben W: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\OSGeo4W/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\script\ScriptEditorDialog.py", line 228, in runAlgorithm
    exec(self.editor.text(), _locals)
  File "<string>", line 24, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: @Hamad, in that case you must have some large polygons which do not have a smaller polygon overlapping them. This was not mentioned in your question. I have updated the script, please try again.

Comment: It works very well. Thank you so much @Ben W

Comment: @Hamad, that's great to hear. You're welcome :-)